# How do I go about tracking down IO usage in Linux and other *nix OS'?

Tags: performance, io

Occasionally, something on my system starts hammering the disk. I would like to log data that would let me know about I/O usage per process, then I could go back to it later and see what keeps doing this. How should I go about solving this problem? Bonus points for solving this for arbitrary block devices.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would give `iotop` a try (Linux only). It is pretty good at giving you the processes with high I/O transfers, but `iotop` is more for displaying the current status than logging.

For logging, `sar` is always a good tool for performance aspects.

Comment: http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/

Comment: worth noting that iotop is linux only. (at least I'm 99% sure it is)

Comment: sar is also available on all unix versions that I ever worked with.

Comment: On Ubuntu systems (this might apply to all Linuxes), there is some debate weather `iotop` works correctly. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/493156

Comment: @Stefan: From what I read that will only affect distributions that have configured their kernel with CONFIG_TASK_DELAY_ACCT enabled.  Is there something else in the thread I missed?