# Monitor hard disk activity

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, hard-disk, monitoring

In a Ubuntu 14.04 server I am experiencing a massive hard disk activity which has no apparent justification: it comes as a burst, it lasts a few minutes and then disappears. It consumes system resources and slows down the whole system.

Is there a (command-line) tool which can be used to monitor the disk activity, listing the *processes* that are using the disk and the *files* involved? Something like htop for the CPU.

Comment: Possible dupe - https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/428/4671

Comment: Did you resolve your issue? I'm experiencing the same thing with several ubuntu 14.04 virtualized servers and I just can't find the cause.

Comment: @pakman Yes, I solved. There were two processes that are well-known to produce such an amount of activity on Ubuntu. If I remember correctly, one of them is `gvfsd-metadata` and the other one has a similar name (anyway, I'm **not sure** about the names: try googling to get more details about them). They continuously explore the filesystem to collect information about files: if they are not necessary for your systems, there is a way to disable their execution.

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/9428/how-can-i-monitor-hard-disk-load-on-linux

Answer (score 33, accepted):

For checking I/O usage I usually use `iotop`.
It's not installed by default on the distro, but you can easily get it with:

```
sudo apt-get install iotop
```

Then launch it with root priviledges:

```
sudo iotop --only
```

The `--only` option will show *only* the processes currently accessing the I/O.

[image: image of iotop in a terminal]

Comment: The `--only` option is really interesting because it will *only show processes or threads actually doing I/O*.

Comment: @A.L good point! that's a very handy option.

Comment: This doesn't show some processes for some reason. My HDD is maxing out at ~150MB/s according to nmon and `iotop` shows no processes except for periodic blips of a few KB/s

Comment: @DouglasGaskell any idea which process is accessing your HDD at that rate? `iotop` has to be launched with `sudo`, so it should see all processes accessing the HDD from all users.

Answer (score 18):

You can try *nmon*

```
sudo apt-get install nmon
```

Try:

```
nmon
```

Output Like below:

[image]

Press d = Disk Press c = CPU Press r = RAM Press q to exit

You can also give try with:

```
iostat
```

Output like below:

```
Linux 3.16.0-30-generic (client01)    03/01/2016      _i686_  (2 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
      39.73   24.58    2.96    0.26    0.00   32.48

Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
sda               3.32        57.31        40.05  119879872   83767716
sdb               1.45        15.02        22.60   31424408   47273012
```

Answer (score 7):

> Something like htop for the CPU.

`atop` - AT Computing's System & Process Monitor

```
# apt-get install -y atop
# atop
```

It has a similar interface to `htop`.

Now press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> - for disk activity

Then press <kbd>c</kbd> - for full command name..

```
  PID  DSK COMMAND-LINE          
28497  37% /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
28496  36% /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
30528  11% mplayer
..........
.....
```

- <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> - CPU
- <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> - Memory
- <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> - Disk
- <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> - Network (However, it may require a kernel patch)

Answer (score 5):

`collectl` tool can also play the role of utilities that are designed with only a specific purpose such as `top`, `ps`, `iotop` and many others.

install:

```
sudo apt-get install collectl
```

For example the following command `collectl -sc` can be used to monitor the summary of the cpu usage.

The following command `collectl -sd` will help you to monitor the disk usage.

You can also use `collectl -sD` to collect data on individual disks, but you have to know that information on total disks will not be reported.

It is very easy to make collectl work as the top utility, just run the following command in your terminal `collectl --top` and you will see the similar output the top tool gives you when it is executed in your Linux system.

to use the collectl utility as the ps tool run the following command in your terminal:

`collectl -c1 -sZ -i:1`

You will get information about processes in your system the same way as you do when you run the `ps` command in your terminal.

you can combine the `t` for tcp and `c` for **cpu** example `collectl -stc`

the summary list of subsystems supported by the tool:

```
b – buddy info (memory fragmentation)
c – CPU
d – Disk
f – NFS V3 Data
i – Inode and File System
j – Interrupts
l – Lustre
m – Memory
n – Networks
s – Sockets
t – TCP
x – Interconnect
y – Slabs (system object caches)
```

`collectl` visualised through graphite or graphiti:

[image]

Comment: Would you mind to provide instructions on how to use collectl visualised through graphite or graphiti? Seems cool!

Comment: How can we get this using graphite?